# putting arrays in this format name:url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not aware of the term of the array but, I have a list of string urls such as `"http://dom/image1.jpg","http://dom/image2.jpg"` that I pulled from an api (api returns just the links). The plugin I am using requires the array to be in the format of

```
{image:"http://dom/image1.jpg"},{image:"http://dom/image1.jpg"}.
```

How do I go from a list of strings to a list with the name: in front of the url

Link to plugin
http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#slides

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 var newArray = array.map(function(item){   
      return { image: item }  /* as key-value pair */
 });
```

Comment: would image be consider a property in this situation? I just would like to know the terminology for this array.

Comment: @user516883: AFAIK, `image` is not a reserved javascript keyword. It is valid usage. You can easily do `array[n].image`. (If that's what you're asking)

Answer (score 5):

Each element in the array you already have is a string, and you want those strings to be wrapped in objects with an `image` property.

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = { image: arr[i] };  // wrap it in an object
}
```